# Will deleting a row from AUTH_USER_MODEL (parent) automatically delete the corresponding row from the referencing(child) table?

Tags: python, django-models

I am new to django models and I am trying to understand the concept here. Suppose I have 2 models/tables named User and Articles.
This the User table and Article table respectively:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   ...

class Article(models.Model):
   author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="child",
   default=None,null=True)
   ...
```

When I delete a row from the User table, will the corresponding row get deleted from Article as well, given I have not set on_default to anything?

Comment: That depends on the `on_delete=...` parameter of the `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 2):

> given I have not set on_default to anything?

You likely mean [**`on_delete=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), you *can't* not set `on_delete`, this is a *mandatory* field since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), hence that means you *have* to specify the parameter.

Before [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), the default value was [**`CASCADE`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE), hence that means that it would indeed remove related `Article`s, but [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11), the last version to support an optional `on_delete` is not supported anymore, since **April 2020**.